# Unhandled exception in for loop

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to create two textures for my OpenGL project. Initially i created the textures seperately and this worked perfectly fine. Not to repeat myself, I decided to attempt to make them as an array and use a for loop to perform the steps twice.

```
unsigned int textures[2];
int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\wall.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
glGenTextures(2, textures);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (i == 0) ? textures[0] : textures[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, (i == 0) ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        if (i == 1)
        data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

On line 13 (`glTexImage2D`), I recive the following unhandled exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x03EE8893 (ig9icd32.dll) in LearnOpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00942000.

Basically I have 3 questions, what is causing this error? How can i fix it? And is this a bad way to go about doing this anyway?

EDIT:

This was my old code, which works perfectly fine:

```
unsigned int texture1, texture2;
// texture 1
// ---------
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
int width, height, nrChannels;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
// The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\wall.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
// texture 2
// ---------
glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
```

Comment: You read the 2nd image twice ("awesomeface.png") and you never free any memory by `stbi_image_free`.

Comment: Not the issue..

Comment: Of course not "the" issue, but another issue.

Comment: I think you should call `stbi_image_free(data);` after `glTexImage2D`

Answer (score 2):

Please read the manuals of the libraries you're using.

[Loading images with stb](https://github.com/senbon/gloom/wiki/Loading-images-with-stb) wrote:

> The fifth parameter of stbi_load() specifies the number of 8-bit components per pixel to use. It can be set to one of following four options:
>
> STBI_grey       = 1
>
> STBI_grey_alpha = 2
>
> STBI_rgb        = 3
>
> STBI_rgb_alpha  = 4

If you pass `0` as the fifth parameter `stbi_load()` will use your `nrChannels` which is uninitialized in your code and thuss causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hey Swordfish! Appreciate you taking the time to look at my post. That being said that answer incomplete. It did not cause any undefined behaviour before it was inside a loop. So what is going on here?

Comment: Also i might add that changing these values do not solve the issue as far as i can tell.

Comment: I'm sorry if the changes don't fix your issue but reading an uninitialized integer is definitely undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ofcourse it is. I do not know how the stbi_load function works, but I apperently its not a problem for it. Atleast not before I reworked it.

Comment: https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h: "The number of components N is 'desired_channels' if desired_channels is non-zero, or *channels_in_file otherwise." so it IS a problem if you pass `0` as fifth parameter and don't initialize what you pass as the fourth one.

Comment: Ive updated the post to show my old code, I do not initialise nrChannels, but the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Behar Code that is undefined may appear to work perfectly fine, but it's till broken and may stop working at any time. You can't determine by running a C++ program whether it has any undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hey moldnilo! I know that, but seeing as this is not fixed bet seeting that value, it does not really matter.